# Binder [IPC] Interface for Java App service called from Native App Service

Tags: java, java-native-interface, ipc, native, android-binder

I am working on adding Native app service on Android platform and wondering if there is right way to complete the interprocess transactions between Java service and Native service.

1. How much is the effort for making it successfully compiling native service on Android platform?
2. Can Binder be used for IPC between two cross-platform services? As I understand there are native binder libraries to extend the interface. How does the transaction between these two take place? Can native app service get access from system for Java service binder?
3. Does binder replace JNI marshalling and unmarshalling work?
4. I believe aidl interfaces will be needed and can be utilized from Java side, I will need to add similar interface in Native component, Is there similar aidl generator from Native side as well? found [this](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/system/tools/aidl/+/brillo-m10-dev/docs/aidl-cpp.md). has anyone utilized it? Is this similar to Java aidls in terms of use/Impl?

Thank you!
Please let me know if you have any questions.

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65284392/aidl-interface-between-java-and-c/65348028#65348028